# Cannot show loaded image with AsyncFileUpload in a Repeater

Tags: asp.net

This is part of a bigger project, but for reasons of clarity I am focusing only on my problem.
Project uses masterpage and in the content page there is a repeater within a panel. In the repeater there is an updatepanel and in it there various panels.
In one of them, there is a table and in it there are an ImageButton, an Image (for the loading animation) and on a different table row there is an Ajax AsynFileUpload control.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">    
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody1">
                    <table style="width:1392px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/placeholder.png" AlternateText="" Width="126" Height="170" OnClick="ImageButton5_Click"/>
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loader.gif"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" UploaderStyle="Modern" ClientIDMode="AutoID" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete = "uploadComplete" ThrobberID="Image1" Width="100" OnClientUploadStarted="AssemblyFileUpload_Started"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

In the header of the Content page there is Javascript script to prevent loading of wrong file type, clearing AsyncFileUpload's text after loading and an alert for errors.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function AssemblyFileUpload_Started(sender, args) {
        var filename = args.get_fileName();
        var ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (ext != 'jpg') {
            throw {
                name: "Wrong file type",
                level: "Error",
                message: "Wrong file type (Only .jpg)",
                htmlMessage: "Wrong file type (Only .jpg)"
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var fileName = args.get_fileName();
        clearContents(sender._element.id, fileName);
    }

    function clearContents(id, fileName) {
        var AsyncFileUpload = $get(id);
        var txts = AsyncFileUpload.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < txts.length; i++) {
            if (txts[i].type == "text") {
                txts[i].value = fileName.slice(0,-4);
                txts[i].style.backgroundColor = "lime";
            }
        }
    }

    function showUploadError(sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_errorMessage());
    }
</script>
```

In the code behind there is:

```
Protected Sub FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim ri As RepeaterItem = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, AsyncFileUpload).NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DirectCast(ri.FindControl(DirectCast(sender, AsyncFileUpload).ID), AsyncFileUpload).FileName)
    DirectCast(ri.FindControl(DirectCast(sender, AsyncFileUpload).ID), AsyncFileUpload).SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/jpg/") + filename)
End Sub
```

So far so good. Everything works perfectly. File is uploaded correctly, Javascript respond OK, all is perfect!
My problem starts when I try to show the uploaded image in the ImageButton control. I just cannot make it happen!

1) I added the following in the FileUploadComplete sub:

```
DirectCast(ri.FindControl("ImageButton5"), ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/jpg/" & filename & ".jpg"
```

It shows NO ERROR, tracking it down all variables have values, but ImageButton ImageUrl is not updated.

2) I tried to do it in the Javascript in the uploadComplete function but I cannot access ImageButton5. Following command returns null Repeater1.

```
var Repeater1 = document.getElementById ('<%=Repeater1.ClientID %>');
```

I am in dead end. Please, help me find out why code behind seems to work but actually doesn't. Or help me get a grip on Repeater1 in Javascript in order to be able to load ImageButton's image as follows:

```
Repeater1.getElementsById("ImageButton5").src == "~/jpg/" + fileName.slice(0, -4) + ".jpg";
```

Thanx in advance....

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#<%=ImageButton5.ClientID%>').attr("src", "~/jpg/" & filename & ".jpg");
            e.preventDefault();
```

do you see a page refresh when you upload the image and submit. 
`e.preventDefault();` is to stop the page to postback. there might be case when you upload the image and page postback and returns with the default value when the page loaded initially. That's my guess.

Comment: Sorry, but I 'm not using jQuery. I really don't know how to use this in Javascript. When I use the following

     var imgbtn = document.getElementById('#<%=ImageButton5.ClientID%>');
            imgbtn.setAttribute("src", "~/pdf/thumbs/" + fileName + ".jpg");

I get imgbtn is null...